# JQuery click() on a div button won't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, simulation

I am trying to emulate a user's click on a site who's code I do not control. The element I am trying to engage with a div acting as button.

```
<div role="button" class="c-T-S a-b a-b-B a-b-Ma oU v2" aria-disabled="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" tabindex="0">
    Generate
</div>
```

The event listeners that are associated with element (according to Chrome's inspector) are:

[image]

And I am simply trying to click the button using:

```
var button = $('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2')
button.click()
```

... but nothing happens. The selector is valid, as verified by:

```
alert($('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').length); // alerts "1"
```

I have tried permutations of all the event handlers

```
button.trigger('click');
button.mouseover().mousedown().mouseup()
button.trigger('mouseover', function() { button.trigger('mousedown', function() { button.trigger('mouseup'); });  });
```

... but still nothing. How can I simulate a click on this div?

In case it is not clear, I am trying to simulate a click on this div and trigger the original function, not define a new click function on the element.

**UPDATE**

Many of these answer do indeed click the button, but don't produce the same result as manually clicking the button. So it appears the problem is not necessarily clicking the button per se, but emulating a *real* click.

Comment: With jQuery, ALWAYS make your selector the first suspect. Check it is actually finding elements before assuming so. Run - `alert($('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').length);` - does it give you 0 or 1? If the former, it's not finding the element.

Comment: I have verified that is not the problem here, but that is solid advice.

Comment: Have you tried using trigger `$('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').trigger('click');`

Comment: OK, next, in the click event callback, add an alert or something. Does it fire?

Comment: `.click()` is a shortcut of `.trigger('click')`

Comment: the alert is never shown in the click() callback

Comment: Try: `button.click(function() { alert('foo'); }).click();`

Comment: `.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2`

Comment: `.trigger('click');` is actually faster than the shortcut `.click();`

Comment: @MartinErnst that does not work also

Comment: can you give the link to the page in which you are trying to do this???

Comment: It's gonna sound shady, but I am working on an iOS app which assists non-technical users generate app specific passwords for google's 2-factor auth page: https://security.google.com/settings/u/0/security/apppasswords

Comment: @coneybeare, please try my solution ( just posted now), let me know, if that helps!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6b4ufsk6/77/) to simulate your "non-clickable" button. The blue div there has the same eventListeners attached as you have shown in your question. Playing around ended up with following results:

1) Let's get the DOM-element first:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2')[0];
```

2) The page doesn't include jQuery. So all eventListeners there are attached by `native .addEventListener()`. If you use jQuery to trigger events, it triggers only the events that are attached by jQuery, but not the native attached events. That means:

```
$(button).trigger('mousedown'); // this doesn't work
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown')); // this should work
```

3) As **Scimonster** pointed out, there is no click-eventListener attached. That means:

```
$(button).trigger('click'); // doesn't work anyway, see 2)
// next works, but has no visible result on the page,
// because there is no click-handler to do anything:
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

4) The click-event fires when the mousebutton goes up. When the `mouseup`-event is used instead it looks like a click. In the fiddle the mouseup makes the red div visible. You may try to trigger the mouseup-event by adding this line to the code:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseup')); // "works", but has no visible result
```

The mouseup-handler is "hidden" by the `mouseover`- and `mouseout`-events, the first attaches it and the latter removes it. That way mouseup has only a result when mouse is over the button. I assume your google-page does something similar to cover the click-event.

5) What you should try:

First trigger some single events in native way:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('eventName'));
```

If that gives no usable results use some reasonable combinations of events:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
// or:
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseup')); // or: .....
```

There are many ways to combine events so that a single event doesn't do anything, but only the right combination works.

**EDIT** According to your invitation to investigate the source I found two ways:

1) The button itself has no eventListeners attached. The button is wrapped in an `<a>`-tag. This tag is parent of the button and its attribute `jsaction` 's value tells that `<a>` has listeners for `click`, `focus`, and `mousedown`. Targeting it directly works:

```
button.parentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

2) If you want to click the button itself you must trigger an event that bubbles up the DOM to reach an element that has a click-handler. But when creating an event with `new Event('name')`, its `bubbles`-property defaults to `false`. **It was my bad not thinking of that.**. So the following works directly on the button:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {bubbles: true}));
```

**EDIT 2** Digging deeper in whats going on on that page yielded an usable result:

It has been found that the page takes care of the mouse-pointer position and right order of the events, probable to distinguish wether a human or a robot/script triggers the events. Therefore this solution uses the `MouseEvent` - object containing the `clientX` and `clientY` properties, which holds the coordinates of the pointer when the event is fired.

A natural "click" on an element always triggers four events in given order: `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `click`. To simulate a natural behaviour `mousedown` and `mouseup` are delayed. To make it handy all steps are wrapped in a function
which simulates 1) enter element at it's topLeft corner, 2) click a bit later at elements center. For details see comments.

```
function simulateClick(elem) {
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(), // holds all position- and size-properties of element
        topEnter = rect.top,
        leftEnter = rect.left, // coordinates of elements topLeft corner
        topMid = topEnter + rect.height / 2,
        leftMid = topEnter + rect.width / 2, // coordinates of elements center
        ddelay = (rect.height + rect.width) * 2, // delay depends on elements size
        ducInit = {bubbles: true, clientX: leftMid, clientY: topMid}, // create init object
        // set up the four events, the first with enter-coordinates,
        mover = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {bubbles: true, clientX: leftEnter, clientY: topEnter}),
        // the other with center-coordinates
        mdown = new MouseEvent('mousedown', ducInit),
        mup = new MouseEvent('mouseup', ducInit),
        mclick = new MouseEvent('click', ducInit);
    // trigger mouseover = enter element at toLeft corner
    elem.dispatchEvent(mover);
    // trigger mousedown  with delay to simulate move-time to center
    window.setTimeout(function() {elem.dispatchEvent(mdown)}, ddelay);
    // trigger mouseup and click with a bit longer delay
    // to simulate time between pressing/releasing the button
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        elem.dispatchEvent(mup); elem.dispatchEvent(mclick);
    }, ddelay * 1.2);
}

// now it does the trick:
simulateClick(document.querySelector(".c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2"));
```

The function does not simulate the real mouse **movement** being unnecessary for the given task.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. While I understand your points, and your Fiddle works as intended using this technique, it appears there may be something else going on on this page where any of the dispatchEvent permutations I have tried fail to yield the same result on the page in question. I have tried mouse over/down/up with a focus event in all possible spots. Not sure what else to try

Comment: @coneybeare :( sorry, I can't think any further myself. I have never heard of a way to render an element immune against events.

Comment: I will be awarding a bounty on this question tomorrow (the soonest SO lets me do so) so if you did want to try and dig deeper to help me solve this perplexing issue, the actual "Generate" button on the page may have more going on: https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Comment: @coneybeare I never wanted to have a google-account, but now I have. I found this issue so interesting that I couldn't wait for the bounty. See my **EDIT** and try yourself:

Comment: Are we looking at the same button? The button on the page I linked to says "Generate" and is not wrapped by an anchor tag. You need to enable 2-factor auth on this new test account before seeing this page. But, following your lead I attempt to send the mousover, mousedown and mouseup events  on the Generate button with the bubbles: true option... nothing. I also tried "click" on it as well.

Comment: The only jsaction attr in the button's lineage that I can see is on the div that contains the entire page's content :/

Comment: @coneybeare Yeah we must be on different pages. Your link takes me to a german page with my account, instead of `2-factor auth` I made german `Bestätigung in zwei Schritten`. But under all pages I can reach is only one with such kind of button, and that's a-wrapped and says `Jetzt starten` instead of `Generate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62278/discussion-between-coneybeare-and-martin-ernst).

Answer (score 0):

`$('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').trigger('click');` does the job - the click event is triggered.

> .trigger() : Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements
>   for the given event type.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```js
$('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').on('click', function() {
   alert( $( this ).text() );
});

$('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="button" class="c-T-S a-b a-b-B a-b-Ma oU v2" aria-disabled="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" tabindex="0">
    Generate
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this shows the new JS behavior, but I need to trigger the original behavior, not a new function

Comment: I am trying to simulate a click, not define a new function on an element.

Comment: $('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').trigger('click'); does exactly that. - simulates the click. Onlcick handler and alert is for demonstration only.

Comment: No, the whole point of the question is that $('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').trigger('click'); does not trigger the click on this element.

Comment: It DOES trigger the click in the snippet in my answer. So your problem is not in trigger() if it does not work on your page

Comment: Precisely. That is the point of this question. "Works for me" answers are not really considered valuable input on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey, that's not "works for me" answer. You can run my snippet on your machine and ensure that the same code works "for you". Click the button.

Comment: PLease reread the question... I am not sure you understand. I dont want to attach a new eventhandler to the button, I need to simulate the click to call the existing function on the button.

Comment: I repeat again: $('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').trigger('click'); simulates the click without attaching any new event handler. Your problem is not in trigger() function but in something else that prevents this function to do its job.

Comment: True, which means this does not answer my question of how can I get the button to fire.

Comment: So, maybe you want to trigger the wrong element which does not have any event listeners attached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62204/discussion-between-coneybeare-and-bancer).

Answer (score -1):

From the image you posted of event handlers, *click is not one of them*. Programmatically triggering a click is not the same as doing so naturally. Mouse enter/leave/press events are not fired here.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but I have tried button.mouseover().mousedown().mouseup() with no success either

Comment: And those events don't fire when you call them directly?

Comment: They do not. This is a google page so they may have extra mechanisms in play idk

Comment: Oh, i should have known. No-one else gives such crazy class names. :P They probably do have other wacky things going on.

Comment: I've seen google create some unexpected events before (in the maps api), so you may be looking for a custom event you need to fire

Comment: @colepanike any advice on how to locate this potential custom event?

Comment: Ooof, it's a toughy with their code. It's highly optimized so it's hard to read and may not even have an intelligible name (I site the very class this question references). The only thing to do is perhaps step through the code as it runs on your natrual click and see what it is doing. I guess it depends on how bad you want it. Sorry man.

Comment: Please note also that this is just a guess, I simply can't think of anything else that might be causing what you're seeing. I'm assuming that you're writing a browser extension and therefore have legitimate access to the page of course. If this is some kind of iframe thing then I'm afraid you may be out of luck.

Comment: It's an iOS app that will take a bit of the pain out of generating app specific pages for non-technical users. thanks for the suggestions

Comment: In that case you could also look for the code it's firing and call it directly, thus skipping the need for simulating the event.

Answer (score -1):

I actually tried on the link you gave and it works. There's no jquery on the page, so have to go by native methods.

```
var click= document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
click.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

document.getElementsByClassName('c-T-S a-b a-b-B')[0].dispatchEvent(click)
```

Comment: make sure you give the proper classname in the above code...the one which actually exists in the DOM (i.e first search the dom for proper classname)....let me know if u still have any problem..

Comment: So this returns true in the console when I run it, but the desired outcome does not occur... meaning nothing happens on the page whereas a real click does the thing I am trying to emulate.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/hcycaakr/) for this and it is working fine. I have used following

```
$('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
$('.c-T-S.a-b.a-b-B.a-b-Ma.oU.v2').click();// This will trigger click event programatically
```

Comment: This just binds a new clickhandler. I am trying to simulate a click, not change it's action.

Comment: @coneybeare , yes, i have tried with second line ".click();", which gots invoked at page load ,and it is working fine. Not sure if i misunderstood your purpose!

Comment: As indicated earlier, it does not accurately emulate a manual click on the page in question.

Comment: When you invoke ".click()", it does programmatic Click, and i thought, this is where you are facing issue, is it correct?